# New editor: how to save versions

Tags: google-apps-script, editor

I loved the straightforward function of saving versions in the old google apps script editor.
In the new editor, this has become very complex. One has to [create deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#new-editor_1), select script types, [switch project types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) and other scary maneuvers. I always shy away from these questions because I am afraid to loose my code.

This is very frustrating, when the only task is to make a code backup within GAS. Moreover, my script is intentionally [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to a Google Sheet, and I suspect that some of those options are not applicable here.

I have not found a good step-by-step instruction on how to save versions in the new IDE for container-bound scripts, neither on SO or in the GAS help. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you really want a way to save your code in a way that you have direct access to it then you might like to consider using the Apps Script API.   You can save the entire code into an ascii text file as JSON and when you want  to restore it you can restore it directly from that JSON file.  Then all of your backups can easily be stored on your computer if you wish.

Comment: You don't really have to mess with the JSON because the restoring functionality uses the JSON file.  If you want to edit it the drop it into an empty container edit it and save the edited version then use that to restore.

Comment: I went into the SERVICES tab of the IDE and tried to find Apps Script API but it was not in the list...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear, but in the docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#new-editor it is apparent that in the new IDE to create a version you **must** create a new deployment. So let's say we want a to create a version of our project (a simple code version, not a version we will use in a production environment), well we still have to "Deploy" the project to save this version.

You ask what type of deployment? It really doesn't matter as any type will result in a new version number that Google automatically increments in integers.

After playing around a bit with deployments I noticed a few things about how they work.

Look at the following image from the "Manage Deployments" modal after a few deployments (versions):

[image]

Notice the "Version 1 Feb 16, 9:51 AM" this is created by Google as described above and in the image.

If you don't understand something please feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Aerials, I proceeded as suggested and have now several test deployments as webApps with tiny differences. But: how to I revoke a deployment/version if I want to go back? In "manage deployments" I tried to select an older deployment and hit "deploy", but there is no change in the code.

Comment: Do you mean, how to edit/view an older version of the code?

Comment: Yes. As probably shines through, I am a novice in programming and every so often I ruin my project and I need to go back to a safe version to start over. In the new editor the function to create versions (and to view and revoke them) has moved to some hidden place.

Comment: I don't believe you can go back. çHave you tried exploring @Coopers mentioned workaround in the comments?

Comment: I did not understand @coopers workaround; it did not look very straighaway, more kind of a hack... I am still hoping that there is a more convenient feature in the editor itself that I am missing. Anyway,  how would I implement the Apps Script API, and how does that give the possibility for backups? Is it a command that needs to be used in code?

Comment: No there isn't a command per se, you would have to implement it, as you say it is kind of hacky

Comment: You could make a feature request to Google if you like by using their [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy but blunt way to backup Your project:
In the spreadsheet, go to FILE/MAKE A COPY.

The copied spreadsheet contains also a copy of Your script project. As long as You leave the copy untouched You can go back to that status. I am not sure if the change log of the spreadsheet also includes a log of Your script changes, I am afraid it doesn't.